# MS Teams: Persistent login for tab app in personal scope

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a MS Teams web app which is loaded as a static tab in the personal scope. I successfully authenticate the user via the Microsoft authentication provider with OpenID and Cookie Authentication. 
The cookies set in the browser have an expiration date which is way into the future.

When the MS Teams desktop app is closed and restarted, it seems that it clears the cookies and the user has to log in again which I would like to avoid. This behavior is different from the MS Teams browser app, where of course the browser respects the expiration date of the cookies and does not clear them, therefore the user can access the app again without logging in.

Is there a way I can overcome this? I have seen some apps running in personal scope where the login is maintained between app restarts, so I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing, maybe in the manifest file?

Comment: We are investigating this.

Comment: @Tudor Are you signing out of Teams or Just restarting the teams desktop client?